# QGIS Server dosen't answer a GetCapabilities request on Debian 8.3

Tags: qgis, debian

Following the server install steps from Q-website and others mentioned,
after I install qgis-server & libapache2-mod-fcgid (and mod enabled),
QGIS Server should answer a GetCapabilities request:

Using my Firefox webbrowser=

> http://localhost/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

which brings up a page stating:

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated
>   with it. The document tree is shown below.

There's to much text to paste here, unless requested.

Am I mistaken to expect some kind of graphic output? NO instructions have described successful output of query.

Then instructs move on to adding a qgis project file.

> ..test the setup using “Add WMS Layer” in QGIS by adding the service
>   URL such as http://localhost/cgi-bin/boundary/qgis_mapserv.fcgi and
>   ticking “Ignore GetMap URI …” and “Ignore GetFeature URI …”.

Response:

> The server you are trying to connect to does not seem to be a WMS
>   server. Please check the URL

A dead-end at every turn..with no "trouble-shooting" instructs included
or explained!

How do I serve maps on the web, using qgis-mapserver?

Comment: ```Am I mistaken to expect some kind of graphic output?``` Yes,  a GetCapabilities response is an XML document with no style attached.

Comment: In the XML response to a GetCapabilities request, can you post the content of one of your layers (XPath like: ```/WMS_Capabilities/Capability/Layer/Layer```)  Do you get a valid legend for your layers (XPath like: ```/WMS_Capabilities/Capability/Layer/Layer/Style/LegendURL/OnlineResource```) ~ you should be able to put that in a browser and get an image

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up...1st comment stops me from banging my head against the wall!

Comment: 2nd comment - I'm totally lost there. I'll try, but I'm a month into learning qgis, so I think I'm going back to reading the training manual again. Simply pointing the browser to the project isn't working. Thanks!

Comment: So the second comment is about how to find a section of the large XML document to show in your question (XPath is a way of navigating XML documents).  Take this example XML response:  [http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_BGS-HPA_Radon_Potential/wms?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&] It has a single real layer of data ```<Name>GBR_BGS-HPA_625K_RADON_POTENTIAL</Name>``` if you follow the XML path (you'll see that this layer section is the layer within the layer within the Capability section within the WMS_Capabilities section ~ the root element).  In this layer section there is a style with URL.